# If Bash arrays can't contain a null string, how does this array do it?

Tags: bash, shell-script, autocomplete, array, null

I've recently discovered that you [can't pass a null string to a Bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24511770/1907765). This is tricky, as I'm trying to insert an empty string value into an array.

I've noticed that the Bash completion variable COMP_WORDS, however, can contain an empty value.

I've written a dummy completion script to illustrate this, with the debugging options on:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 _comp() {
  3     set -xv
  4     for i in ${!COMP_WORDS[@]}; do
  5         echo "<${COMP_WORDS[$i]}>"                                                                                         
  6     done
  7     set +xv
  8     local cur=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}
  9 
 10     local arr=(apple banana mango pineapple)
 11     COMPREPLY=()
 12     COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${arr[*]}" -- $cur))
 13 
 14 }
 15 
 16 complete -F _comp dummy
```

If I source this file, and then enter the following:

```
dummy apple   banana
```

And then if I move the cursor back to the middle space between apple and banana (indicated below by an underscore) ...

```
dummy apple _ banana
```

And then if I hit tab, I get the following output from the resulting debug, showing four array elements, 'dummy' 'apple' '' 'banana'

```
for i in '${!COMP_WORDS[@]}'
+ echo '<dummy>'
<dummy>
+ for i in '${!COMP_WORDS[@]}'
+ echo '<apple>'
<apple>
+ for i in '${!COMP_WORDS[@]}'
+ echo '<>'
<>
+ for i in '${!COMP_WORDS[@]}'
+ echo '<banana>'
<banana>
```

So the COMP_WORDS array is clearly capable of storing a null string of some kind. Although interestingly, this does **not** happen if I use a regular for loop, accessing the array elements rather than the indices. I.e., if I change the for loop in the debug section to this ...

```
for i in ${COMP_WORDS[@]}; do
    echo "<$i>"
done
```

Then I get the following debug output showing only three array elements: 'dummy' 'apple' 'banana'

```
for i in '${COMP_WORDS[@]}'
+ echo '<dummy>'
<dummy>
+ for i in '${COMP_WORDS[@]}'
+ echo '<apple>'
<apple>
+ for i in '${COMP_WORDS[@]}'
+ echo '<banana>'
<banana>
```

And I've tried echoing the length of the array with `${#COMP_WORDS[@]}` - for this input, it shows a length of four. So it clearly does contain four elements, one being a null string.

This seems like really strange behaviour to me. My question is twofold:

1. What is the explanation for the COMP_WORDS array being able to store null strings when normal arrays apparently cannot?
2. Why am I unable to see the null string when I use a regular for loop, but I can see it when I access the elements of the array by their indices?

Comment: empty string is not _Null_ `\0`; `arr=( "" "" "" ); echo ${#arr[@]}`, result `3`

Comment: Ah okay. So then I'm wondering - why can I not access these elements using an ordinary for loop?

Comment: @Lou If you expand the array without double-quotes, word splitting will effectively remove any null elements (and mangle any containing whitespace, and possibly other things). So use `for i in "${COMP_WORDS[@]}"; do`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! I must remember to quote everything it seems.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be confusing the empty string `""` with the NULL character `\0`. They are not the same. You can use empty strings in arrays and variables:

```
$ a=(aa "" "b")
$ echo "${#a[@]}"
3
$ printf -- '- %s\n' "${a[@]}"
- aa
- 
- b
$ for i in "${a[@]}"; do
> printf '%s\n' "$i"
> done
aa

b
```

Some of the [conditional expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) in Bash even allow testing whether a string is empty:

> -z string
>
> ```
> True if the length of string is zero.
> ```
>
> -n string string
>
> ```
> True if the length of string is non-zero.
> ```

See also [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

Comment: Oh right, okay. So I guess the question then becomes, why can't I access empty strings in arrays using a regular for loop?

Comment: You can, you just have to quote the reference to the array in the loop header (`"${a[@]}"` instead of `${a[@]}`).

Comment: Ah, thanks! Still taking me a while to wrap my head around Bash.

Comment: If you're new to bash (or, well, even if you're not :-) ), you can use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your script for any of the common errors. It's a really valuable tool.